# Можно задать стиль к тегам fieldset и legend?

Tags: css

Можно задать стиль к тегам fieldset и legend?

Comment: Вкратце: можно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<fieldset> и <legend>
```

Сделай так

```
<fieldset class="one"> и <legend class="two">
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Так пробовали?

```
fieldset{
  border:solid 1px #224466;
}

legend{
  border:solid 1px #ccddee;
}
```